can the term "currency" and "money" be interpreted include cryptocurrencies in a software patent?
The software patent application requires the use of something of value as currency for transactions. As such, it lists "real currency", which is also described as "money", as possible options.
Questions:

based on such usage, could it be broad enough to include cryptocurrencies?
could it also be broad enough to include any currency of any country?


It depends on context and please talk to your patent practitioner rather than ask the internet.
